# How python flask server send back response with XML file

Tags: python, xml, flask

I coded a mock server, after I got a POST message with XML file, I need send back a response message with XML file also.
I found some example as below to send back response with XML content. But I think it's not a file. Anyone has idea on sending back response with a file?

```
result = open('output.xml', 'r').read()
r = Response(response=result, status=200, mimetype="application/xml")
```

Comment: `result` is a string, not a file to be returned. See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.send_file

Comment: thanks, I will take a look!

Comment: I updated my comment, but also searching for "flask return file for download" shows several results. XML shouldn't matter

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works with  send_from_directory("xml/", "output.xml", as_attachment=True)